# fix doScript function error in InDesign script

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

I wrote a script for InDesign and used doScript to run a bat file. This script works on some systems and not on others.
The error is in the image.

[image]

I run as admin InDesign. But it gives another error.

[image]

How can I fix the error?

```js
function batFile(str) {
    var path = "~\\AppData\\Roaming\\test\\";
    var filename = 'b1.bat';

    var file1 = new File(path + filename);
        file1.encoding = 'UTF-8';
        file1.open('w');
        var txt = "systeminfo | findstr /B /C:\"OS Name\" /C:\"OS Version\">%appdata%\\test\\t1.txt"
        file1.write(txt);
        file1.close();

    var cmdcode = "CreateObject(\"WScript.Shell\").Run \"%appdata%\\test\\b1.bat\", 0, True";
    app.doScript(cmdcode, ScriptLanguage.visualBasic, undefined, UndoModes.FAST_ENTIRE_SCRIPT);
    var result = path + "t1.txt";
    var arry = openFile2(result);
    
    if (arry.length != 0) {
        return arry;
    } else {
        return "null";
    }
}
```

**

### Update

I find the problem.
When a user name is composed of two parts, such as "your name" causes this problem. To address this issue, we need to put the address in two double quotations.

```
var txt = "systeminfo | findstr /B /C:\"OS Name\" /C:\"OS Version\">\"%appdata%\\test\\t1.txt"\"
```

### **
Update 2

In Windows, when the user uses OneDrive, the AppData path also changes, which causes doScript not to run. for example:

c: \ users \ username \ appdata

Changes to:

c: \ users \ username \ onedrive \ appdata

Comment: This is the issue running code within code and making assumptions about where the problems reside. What you don’t make clear is you are running a JavaScript through InDesign that dynamically builds a bat file then uses VBScript commands via the `doScript()` method to execute the bat file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell what the problem with your script. But just in case, you can run bat file this way:

```
var bat_file = File("your_file.bat");
bat_file.execute();
```

### Update

Based on your code I can offer the workaround: add `& echo ok > %appdata%\\test\\ok.txt` in your bat file and check if the file `ok.txt` exists before going further.

```
function batFile(str) {
    var path = "~\\AppData\\Roaming\\test\\";
    var filename = 'b1.bat';

    var file1 = new File(path + filename);
        file1.encoding = 'UTF-8';
        file1.open('w');
        var txt = "systeminfo | findstr /B /C:\"OS Name\" /C:\"OS Version\">%appdata%\\test\\t1.txt";
        // add the file 'ok.txt' after the previous command is finished
        txt += " & echo ok > %appdata%\\test\\ok.txt";
        file1.write(txt);
        file1.close();

    // run the bat file
    file1.execute();

    // check if the file 'ok.txt' exists before going further
    var ok = File(path + "ok.txt");
    while (!ok.exists) $.sleep(100);
    ok.remove();

    // do stuff
    var result = path + "t1.txt";
    var arry = openFile2(result);

    if (arry.length != 0) {
        return arry;
    } else {
        return "null";
    }
}
```

Comment: After running doScript, a file will be created which I will call later.
I tested your method. The method you mentioned creates a problem, and that is that there seems to be a process in executing the code. This means that the rest of the script code is executed at the same time as Execute.

Comment: Good luck. But I doubt that someone can help you with no your code and no infomation about what exactly your code is doing. Probably the stupid `pause / sleep()` or `file.exists` will be enough, but it's impossible to tell

Comment: It looks like a VBS glitch. I just updated my answer. Btw, note, you didn't even mention that you're using VBS, but most likely this was a root of the porblem. This is why a code is necessary almost always.

Comment: Thanks Yuri Khristich.I tested the file.execute() and it worked fine. but I have a problem with execute(). command pattern window will open when I use this function. Is there a way not to show it?

Comment: I'm not sure, what do you mean 'command pattern window'? If you mean cmd.exe window, alas, as far as I know, it's impossible to hide it in this case.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. I meant the same CMD (Command prompt).

Comment: The script does not work again.
My own script and your script.
Windows don't seem to allow the script to create the file in the location, that doScript to execute it. would you have any idea.
I find this link: https://community.adobe.com/t5/after-effects/create-a-txt-file-in-extendscript/m-p/9645024.
but not work in indesign

Comment: Hi, `doScript()`? I don't use it in my snippet. I use `file.execute()`. As for a folder, I usually save and run such temporary files in user's Temp folder. Extend script has the native variable for that: `Folder.temp`. I can't check in right now but it always worked with no problem. Try the temp folder. Although it's not unlikely that yet another bloody security Windows update broke everything. If so, It would be sad, and for now I have no idea how it could be fixed.

Comment: :(  I want to save the file forever. If user clean the temp folder, my file removed and script not work.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug reported in the UserVoice: https://indesign.uservoice.com/forums/601180-adobe-indesign-bugs/suggestions/41072476-type-library-is-not-automatically-created-by-cc202. A common trick to solve this is, run InDesign at least once *as administrator* on the client machine. This activates VBS support.

Comment: I have seen this link before.
I tested with the 2015, 2020 and 2021 versions. Some systems have no problems running, but others give errors.

Comment: I would be checking the various levels of UAC (User Account Control) on each system along with whether Admin Approval mode is enabled in the Local Security Policy as this could affect how running as administrator will behave and might explain the inconsistency.